# Divide by zero error Only When use parameter in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, hadoop

There are two table, **external table A** and **view table B**.
Data in external table is connected to Hadoop through Polybase.
View table is union all external table A and other external table (similar A).

For example:

```
A:
--------------------
number  | time
--------------------
0       |2018-09-10
1       |2018-09-10
2       |2018-09-10
--------------------

B:
--------------------
number  | time
--------------------
0       |2018-09-10
1       |2018-09-10
2       |2018-09-10
3       |2018-09-11
--------------------
```

> Now, I don't know why below SQL make results different?

And I find different order of execution in these SQL. In case 1 & 2, "select 5.0/number" is executed first. In case 3 & 4, where clause is executed first.

case 1

```
DECLARE @date datetime ='2018-09-10';
select 5.0/number  
from A 
where time = @date and number > 0 

Result: 
Cannot execute the query "Remote Query" against OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)". [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Divide by zero error encountered.
```

case 2

```
DECLARE @date datetime ='2018-09-10';
select 5.0/temp.number 
from
(
    select number as number 
    from A
    where time = @date and number > 0 
)temp

Result: 
Cannot execute the query "Remote Query" against OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)". [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Divide by zero error encountered.
```

case 3

```
select 5.0/number 
from A 
where time = '2018-09-10' and number > 0 

Result:
5.0
2.5
```

case 4 (from B)

```
DECLARE @date datetime ='2018-09-10';
select 5.0/number  
from B
where time = @date and number > 0 

Result:
5.0
2.5
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What data type is `number`?

Comment: I think you could use case when statements to capture the divide by zero errors.

Comment: What ***exactly*** do you want the result of `5.0 / 0` to be?  You could use `CASE WHEN number = 0 THEN -1 ELSE 5.0 / number END` or you could use `5.0 / NULLIF(number, 0)` *(to get a NULL result)*, or even `5.0 / (number + 1)` to avoid the error *(if you number number is always >= 0)*.  But ***you*** need to define the business logic as to what you need to happen...

Comment: number  type is int.

Comment: As for why `Case3` and `Case4` are different; what datatype is `time` in the source tables, and are you *sure* that there isn't a value for '2018-09-10' in table B?

Comment: I know I can use `case when`, but I'm still confused this condition.   I'm sorry about `Case 4`. I write _wrong_ result . Correct: only 5.0 and 2.5.   `Time` type is `datetime`. Thank you!!

Comment: In which case, I agree, it doesn't appear to make much sense.  Are you able to profile the queries actually being executed against Hadoop?  *(A linked server is basically the SQL Server running some SQL against your Hadoop cluster, then running some SQL locally, if necessary/optimal, then returning the results.  It ***feels*** like all of the SQL is running on Hadoop and the divide by zero is happening there.  In which case, knowing the exact SQL running in Hadoop would be useful to know.)*

Comment: I have a small hunch that turning the queries against the remote A table into [dynamic sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) could help.

Answer (score 0):

Does this also yield an error?

```
DECLARE @date datetime ='2018-09-10';
select 5.0/temp.number 
from
(
    select time, number
    from A
    where number > 0 
)temp
where temp.time = @date
```